# Ionic 2 pasar información entre modal y page

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0

Tengo un form el cual solicito el pais, el cual es mostrado en una modalPage. Quiero que al seleccionar el pais me devuelva el valor del pais a la page padre (la page que contiene el boton del modal)

Comment: Por favor, incluye un [mcve] donde podamos ver cuál es el problema con más detalle. Ya hay varias preguntas en SOes sobre cómo pasar información de un modal a otra página y viceversa. ¿Cómo es esta pregunta diferente?

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes pasar la información a través de `Input()` y `Output()`, es un poco largo de explicar pero yo te recomendaría **Output()** en el cual puedes enviar el valor del país a través de **Emitters** y reconocerlo con el hook **OnChanges**.

Consulta la documentación de la interacción entre componentes para poderlo comprender más a fondo en: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

debes poner este evento en el formulario padre

```
  //este metodo se ejecuta cuando se cierra el dialogo 
  miModal.onDidDismiss( tuParametroDelModal=>{
   if(tuParametroDelModal){

    }

 })
```

En el modal debes hacer lo siguiente

```
cerrarModal(){
 this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.tuParametro)
```

}